# alsoResize not also resizing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have two boxes which are draggable and resizeable. The boxes drag and resize but not the images within... is this how it should work?

JQuery:

```
$( "#draggableNW" ).draggable().resizable({
    alsoResize: '#img1',
    aspectRatio: true
});
$( "#draggableNE" ).draggable().resizable({
    alsoResize: '#img2',
    aspectRatio: true
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="draggableNE" class="ne" style="width:100px; height:60px; z-index:30; position:absolute; background:blue">
<img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" width="100" id="#img2"></img>
</div>
<div id="draggableNW" class="nw" style="width:100px; height:60px; z-index:30; position:absolute; right:0; background:red;">
<img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" width="100" id="#img1"></img>
</div>
```

Fiddle:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cw4Q7/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to remove "#" in the id attribute of your img element.

Comment: Aarrrggghhh - what a ****! Thanks, sometimes you can look too hard for too long and the schoolboy errors will get you!